# Can I get the limits of the stack in C / C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

My question is pretty simple and straightforward: if I have e.g. 1MB of RAM assigned to the program's stack, can I get the addresses of the start and the end, or the start and the length?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I think it's OS specific, so I can't help you, but I am interested in the answer...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block

Comment: I guess you aren't really interested in anything but free stack left, right?

Comment: There is no *portable* way to do this.

Comment: There are some good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827/checking-available-stack-size-in-c

Comment: It might be not very easy or meaningful to get the exact end of stack... And it is implementation specific (what operating system & version, what compiler & optimization flags, what system configuration)

Comment: @Brain: The TEB doesn't have the maximum stack size though, see http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/07/15/checking-for-sufficient-stack-space/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should question your assumptions about stack layout.

Maybe [the stack doesn't have just one top and bottom](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks)

Maybe [it has no fixed bottom at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14471564/103167)

Clearly there's no portable way to query concepts which are not portable.

From Visual C++, though, you can use the Win32 API, depending on Windows version.

On Windows 8 it is very easy, just call [`GetCurrentThreadStackLimits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706789(v=vs.85).aspx)

Earlier versions need to use [`VirtualQueryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and process the results somewhat.  Getting one address in the stack is easy, just use `&` on a local variable.  Then you need to find the limits of the reserved region that includes that address.  Joe Duffy has written [a blog post showing the details of finding the bottom address of the stack](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/07/15/checking-for-sufficient-stack-space/)

Comment: As [Thread Stack Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says, *default* initial and reserve sizes can be obtained from the PE header (it doesn't specify *which module's* header).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: That's the stack size for the main thread only, although it also serves as a default for threads created later, their size is set dynamically.  And of course it is the PE header of the executable image, the one matching `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`.

Comment: Your assumption that Visual C++ == Win32 isn't going to be sound [much longer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/12/cross-platform-mobile-development-with-visual-c.aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That page is playing fast and loose with the name "Visual C++".  Yes, the Visual Studio development environment may target other platforms, even C++ native development on other platforms, but it is being done via toolchain plugins for compilers other than Visual C++, not by adding other platforms to the Visual C++ toolchain.  Would be a better argument using Windows Store API, which isn't Win32 and is done with the Visual C++ toolchain.

Comment: @BenVoigt: the *default* stack size specified in the PE header doesn't *always* get applied to secondary threads. The caller decides that when calling `CreateThread()`/`_beginthread/ex()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, that's why I said it's not the stack size for secondary threads, only a default.

Answer (score 10):

`GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` seems to do what you're looking for, getting the lower/upper boundaries of the stack into pointer addresses:

```
ULONG_PTR lowLimit;
ULONG_PTR highLimit;
GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(&lowLimit, &highLimit);
```

Looks like it is only available on Windows 8 and Server 2012 though.

Check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh706789(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows before 8, implement GetCurrentThreadStackLimits() yourself:

```
#include <windows.h>
#if _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0602
VOID WINAPI GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(LPVOID *StackLimit, LPVOID *StackBase)
{
    NT_TIB *tib = (NT_TIB *) NtCurrentTeb();
    *StackLimit = tib->StackLimit;
    *StackBase = tib->StackBase;
}
#endif
```

Comment: From the Joe Duffy article I linked in my answer: *Unfortunately, the `StackLimit` is only updated as you actually touch pages on the stack, and thus **it’s not a reliable way to find out how much uncommitted stack is left**. The CLR uses `kernel32!VirtualAlloc` to commit the pages, not by actually moving the guard page, so **`StackLimit` is not updated as you might have expected.***  But if you read the comments under the question before answering, you would already have known that the TIB does not contain the needed information.

Comment: @BenVoigt TIB does contain the information. The "low" value that GetCurrentThreadStackLimits returns is the undocumented `DeallocationStack` field, located at `FS:[0xE0C]` (x86) / `GS:[0x1478]` (x64). At least since Windows 2000. So, one may use undocumented field on OS prior to Win8, and use GetCurrentThreadStackLimits on Win8+.

Comment: @Alex: Perhaps, but this answer references the `StackLimit` field which gives wrong results.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, should someone edit the answer then? It is a valid answer (considering the "fix") - certainly better than the accepted answer suggests (call into kernel via `VirtualQuery`). I don't have enough expierence in MS C++ to properly write that.

Comment: @Alex: I still stand by my answer... it works correctly on all platforms, while pulling the undocumented field out of the TIB requires per-platform code.