# Install CLAPACK-3.2.1 in fedora 23

Tags: lapack, fedora-23

Hi I use fedora23 to calculate matrix.
So I am trying to install CLAPACK-3.2.1 to my computer.

In the procedure,
1. download clapack.tgz (version 3.2.1) from www.netlib.org/clapack -> done
2. cd CLAPACK-3.2.1 and cp make.inc.example make.inc -> done
3. make f2clib -> done properly
4. make blaslib -> done properly
5. make (this takes a while) -> problem starts here.

## in a procedure of make, there are two errors. The error message is this.

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/optics/CLAPACK/TESTING/EIG'
NEP: Testing Nonsymmetric Eigenvalue Problem routines
./xeigtstz < nep.in > znep.out 2>&1
/bin/sh: line 1:  9412 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./xeigtstz < nep.in > znep.out 2>&1
Makefile:438: recipe for target 'znep.out' failed
make[1]: *** [znep.out] Error 139
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/optics/CLAPACK/TESTING'
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'lapack_testing' failed
make: *** [lapack_testing] Error 2
```

==============================================================================

I cannot understand this. Please help me dealing with these errors.

Answer (score 4):

I have also encountered this problem and was able to resolve it by increasing the stack size using ulimit [as suggested here](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1596). The following worked for me:

```
$ sudo ulimit -s 100000
```

Followed by running make as usual. If you would like a primer on what this command does, check out this question: [What does “ulimit -s unlimited” do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471564/what-does-ulimit-s-unlimited-do). Basically, it increases the limits on the scratch space in memory allocated to a thread.

Comment: @JWShim : I'm replying to your answer below here. It looks like the permissions in the INSTALL directory are not set to allow you to create or execute. Try running
    '$ sudo make'
or 
    '$ sudo chmod 777 -R CLAPACK-3.2.1'

Comment: Solved the problem for me as well. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu 17.10 it worked in this way:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```